# What to use to design look and feel for a .NET application?

Tags: .net, wpf

I've been tasked with designing a new look and feel/navigation for a .NET application that is in the works but I am not sure what the best way to approach this would be.

I'm not a programmer. I have designed webpages through photoshop and am able to convert them to static HTML through limited HTML knowledge.

WPF has been suggested but that would mean I would require a VS license? Would that mean I would need to learn the program too? I have used VB/VBA ages ago briefly.

I assume I can't just do it in photoshop? Or can I?

Comment: Are you designing the wireframes for an application that will be implemented later by a software developer, or are you tasked with rewriting the UI itself?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need to design the look or implement it as well?

You can design it in anything you like if someone else is going to implement your vision, although you might want to consult with a developer along the way to make sure your vision is actually doable.

If you also need to implement it and WPF is the chosen platform, I suggest looking into [Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) which is a UI editor for WPF. You can also create UIs manually using [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) and your favourite text editor, but that's probably more complex than dragging a few controls around in Blend.

I recommend learning Blend and the basics of WPF architecture. Between that and hopefully constant communication with the dev team, you should be good to go. But, 
there are tools that will allow you to [export from Photoshop to WPF-compatible XAML](http://uxconfidential.typepad.com/ux_confidential/2008/06/exporting-xaml-from-photoshop-illustrator.html), so that may be worth investigating as well. I don't have personal experience with them, so I can't recommend much or speak to their quality.

Ultimately, the choice of platform and UI toolkit should be up to more than just you. If the company chooses other toolkits for the application such as Silverlight or the older Windows Forms, your options may be somewhat different. Silverlight uses a similar approach to WPF, so Blend can still help you out. With Windows Forms, you're likely going to be limited to just designing mock screenshots or learning Visual Studio.

Comment: There's quite a few tools that will allow you to export from photoshop and illustrator to XAML. http://uxconfidential.typepad.com/ux_confidential/2008/06/exporting-xaml-from-photoshop-illustrator.html

Comment: Tending to give -1... WPF is a good technology, Blend would bea good tool MADE FOR DESIGN. And then one could also get into all the more advanced items (mouse over etc.) but then the OP is not really a designer for programs it seems either.

Comment: @TomTom I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow. I think my answer says more or less the same thing as your comment. Did I miss something?

Comment: The tone maybe. I also did not downvote it... This is a very tricky question. And the poster has not even decided on a technology. This discussion goes into the wrong direction - for example. WPF should not be suggested but decided, and not by the designer.

Comment: @TomTom Correct, I'm not a designer for programs. Our devs are working on converting a VB program to .NET and my company wants it to look more modern (Our devs will code it and the design but making it visually appealing is not their strong suit - which is where I come in). Since they asked me to re-design it I assume it will retain the old VB look and feel.

Comment: @TomTom Ahh, I see your point. I misread the question as saying WPF has been chosen. I attempted to clarify my post a bit and add some side information.

Comment: I strongly suggest going with WPF - and getting a third party suite of controls to add on top of what MS offers. THAT SAID: It will be painfull on both sides. Your developers will struggle with it. if they make it, the result will be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had my biggest improvements when using a 3rd-party-component for GUI elements like DevExpress or Telerik or Infragistics.

(We chose DevExpress after lots of try-and-error).

While I'm no designer, but a developer with some basic design skills, I decided that it is more cost-effective for me to simply use something that is already polished and needs no design work by myself.

On the other hand, e.g. [DevExpress has a nice skin editor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#SkinEditor/CustomDocument2547) which you could use in a high-level manner to fine-tune a skin or even design a new skin from scratch.

**Update:**

It seems that their skin editor only supports Windows Forms but not WPF. For WPF, they only have [certain predefined skins](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Themes/).